# JUnit Test for Dao and Service with Arquillian

Tags: unit-testing, junit, wildfly, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian

Hi I'm trying to test my Service and Dao layers for a Java EE 7 application.

So I looking for testing solutions follow tutorials using Arquillian with junit test and wildfly remote dependence.

Dao and Service interfaces with relative implementations have been created, following my junit test with Arquillian:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GenericServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml",
                        "persistence.xml")
                .addClasses(EmployeeDao.class, EmployeeDaoImpl.class,
                        EmployeeService.class, EmployeeServiceImpl.class,
                        Employee.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void should_crud() {
        // Gets all the objects
        assertNotNull(employeeService);
        Employee employee = employeeService.get(new Integer(1));
        assertNotNull(employee);
    }
}
```

Running class as JUnit Test it doesn't work with this error:

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"deployment\" => \"test.war\")]' not found"

Test pass if any classes has been added to ShrinkWrap as following:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GenericDaoTest {
@Inject
private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestableDeployment() {
        final JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    return jar;
    }

    @Test
    public void should_crud() {
    }

}
```

How can I create a working test using arquillian for Java EE 7 adding service class implementations?

And I have To add every Class and Intefaces that have to be called (for example all entities,dao etc classes) or only Service Interface and implementation Class?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The deployment `test.war` is not found by the server because there're error(s) during the creation of this archive. So the first thing you need to do is to increase the Java EE container's logger level from _INFO_ to _DEBUG_ to see the complet error during the creation of your deployment. By the way, is there particular reason of creating a Java archive (JAR)? We normally deploy a Web archive (WAR) to the Java EE container.

Comment: I followed some tutorials and example in Java EE7 petstore github project https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee7

Answer (score 0):

Since you're developing a javaee application, I would suggest you to create a War archive instead of Jar. 
You can add the whole package using

`ShrinkWrap.addPackages(true, "com.yourpackage.name")` so you don't have to add your classes independently.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to test a war archive.
If this is the case you should change

```
return ShrinkWrap
          .create(JavaArchive.class)
```

to

```
return ShrinkWrap
          .create(WarArchive.class)
```

In addition you should add your persistence.xml file to the META-INF folder like:

```
.addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
```

If you want to use the annotation @Transactional in your tests, you need to add a few dependencies to your test scope. If you didn't add them yet you can read at http://arquillian.org/modules/transaction-extension/ what dependencies to add.